# capturing everything vs. capturing only some in a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Every now and then I come up with code like this:

```
// lazy lambda:
[&] {
// use references to a, b, c
}

// pedantic lambda
[&a, &b, &c] {
// use references to a, b, c
}
```

I'd like to know which of the lambdas is better in terms of performance and perhaps executable size according to the C++14 standard (or later) and your practical experience with compilers.

Comment: If the lazy lambda ends up capturing the same variables as the pedantic lambda, I see no reason why the performance or even the generated machine codes should differ.

Comment: IDK if it is allowed per the standard or not but I would think the compiler would only capture the variables you use.

Comment: The difference is purely syntactic, not semantic. Both lambdas do the same thing.

Comment: I often read that references are implemented as pointers, so storing all references in a scope might well use up more space without optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excluding the trivial case where you explicitly capture something that isn't mentioned in the lambda at all, there are two corner cases where there might be a difference.

First, implicit captures generally do not capture entities that aren't odr-used (but see the next item for the exception to this). This includes, among other things, things mentioned in unevaluated operands such as those of `decltype` and `sizeof`, as well as certain `const` and `constexpr` local variables when used in certain contexts (consult [[basic.def.odr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr) for the full set of rules):

```
void f(int){}
void f2(const int &) {}
void t() {
    const int x = 8;
    constexpr double y = 8;
    const double z = 8; 
    auto g = []{ f(x); }; // OK
    auto g1 = [=]{ f(x); }; // OK, does not capture x

    // usually won't fire, though not guaranteed
    static_assert(sizeof(g) == sizeof(g1), "!!"); 

    auto g2 = []{ f(y); }; // OK
    auto g3 = []{ f(z); }; // Error, must capture z

    auto g4 = []{ f2(x); };  // Error, must capture x since it's odr-used
    auto g5 = [=]{ f2(x); }; // OK, captures x
    auto g6 = []{ f2(+x); }; // OK, doesn't odr-use x
    auto g7 = []{ f2(y); };  // OK
}
```

If you write the capture list manually, it's possible that you'll capture more than you technically need to, because the rules governing what is or isn't odr-used are pretty complex.

Second, implicit captures in generic lambdas will capture things used in a dependent expression, even when they aren't necessarily odr-used, for sanity. Borrowing [an example from the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#12):

```
void f(int, const int (&)[2] = {})    { }   // #1
void f(const int&, const int (&)[1])  { }   // #2
void test() {
  const int x = 17;
  auto g2 = [=](auto a) {
    int selector[sizeof(a) == 1 ? 1 : 2]{};
    f(x, selector);  // OK: is a dependent expression, so captures x
                     // Will actually odr-use x only if sizeof(a) == 1
  };
}
```

However, you are not actually required to capture something that may-or-may-not-be-odr-used when writing a generic lambda; you are only required to capture it if you instantiate a specialization of the function call operator that odr-uses the thing. And so if you never call the resulting generic lambda in a way that would odr-use the thing at issue, then the implicit capture may capture more than the minimum you need. For example, this is allowed:

```
void test() {
  const int x = 17;
  auto g3 = [](auto a) { // no capture
    int selector[sizeof(a) == 1 ? 1 : 2]{};
    f(x, selector);  // OK for now
  };
}
```

as long as you don't call `g3` with anything whose size is 1: `g3(0)` is OK on typical systems; `g3('\0')` isn't.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in this example. The compiler will only capture variables that are explicitly referenced in the lambda, making the lazy capture equivalent to the explicit one.

A lazy capture is slightly more convenient. Changing the body of the lambda to use additional captured variables, or removing all references to a captured variable from an existing lambda, would normally also require updating an explicit capture list. With a lazy capture the compiler will do everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

Like people said above, there will be no difference in regards to generated code. However, I believe, it is better to be explicit - it gives better readability (easier to reason about variable life cycle) and also gives you better support from the compiler, producing errors when you access the variable you didn't mean to.

I believe 'lazy capturing' to be not a good feature at all.